# Select column using includes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

My query was as: `Message.joins(:user).select('messages.*, users.name').where("users.name LIKE ? OR messages.to LIKE ? " ,"%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)`. I want to use includes instead of joins. So I changed the query to: `Message.includes(:user).select('messages.*, users.name').where("users.name LIKE ? OR messages.to LIKE ? " ,"%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)`.

In my views I looped the messages and I got user name using: <%= message.name %>. But after changing the joins to includes I am getting the  error : `NoMethodError (undefined method`name' for #)`. How can I access fields from messages table and users table in my views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code.

@messages.each do |message|
  <%= message.user.name %>
end